# how to get a list of all keys that are pressed Python

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

I cant seem to find a way to get all pressed keys. My end goal is to have different keyboard shortcuts for an application I am making such as opening a new window when the user has the r + a keys pressed. pygame seems to have a very good system for this but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with tkinter.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried using pygames event system but that only worked if my mouse was in the window when i pressed the keys, i also tried the keyboard module but i was only able to get that to work with one key.